# PyQt4 - Smooth window resize transition?

Tags: python, qt, windows-7, resize, transition

When a User opens a particular tab inside the QMainWindow of my PyQt4 driven GUI,
the window needs to be automatically resized so that the contents of this particular tab will fit.

As you know, when using Qwidget.resize(), the Window (by default on PC) is instantly resized.
This isn't easy on the eyes and would probably surprise / confuse the User.

Is it possible to have the window smoothly transition into the new window size?
(An animation in essence)

(For instance, a really horrible method would be to continuously call resize, each time slightly increasing the window size to elude to a transition)

The window size is not adjustable to the User, so when the window exands and shrinks to and from the different sizes, I know their exact dimensions. It is also known to me that all my Users run Windows 7 (Since my users are school mates in a tablet program).

Does anybody know if this is possible with PyQt4, and how to achieve it?
(Qt Kinetic sounded relevant to me, but it's proven difficult to search for the appropriate information)

Thanks! x 100

Specs:
- PyQt4
- Python 2.7
- Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [QPropertyAnimation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qpropertyanimation.html) which can be used to animate QObject properties, including the size of your window.

I'm not sure if it will work well performance wise, since it will call resize() perpetually, as you say, but it seems like that is what you want.

What you could maybe do is to resize the window, but somehow disable painting (i.e. override `paint()`)  during that animation, so that only the frame is smoothly resized (should be ok) and the interior is not redrawn until the target size has been reached.

Comment: Worked a treat!
Was snagged by the whole 'child widget' thing, but resolved now.

Thanks!

Comment: On a relevant note, is there an easy way to disable the window from User resizing after the animation? (Setting maximum and minimum Geometrys interfere with the transition)

Comment: @AntiEarth: Maybe WindowFlags or QWidget::attribute has some way to disable window resizing. I'm sure it's possible, but don't know it from heart. Look at the docs for QWidget.