# PyQt: How to animate dialog size

Tags: python, pyqt

A code below creates a single QWidget window with QPushButton connected to resizeDialog(). Pressing a button switches a dialog's size from .resize(200,100) to .resize(600,300) and back.

Question: By default the transition from one window's size to another happens instantly. How to override this behavior with an animation?

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class myWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        myLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        Button = QtGui.QPushButton('Resize')
        myLayout.addWidget(Button)
        Button.setMinimumWidth(200)
        Button.clicked.connect(self.resizeDialog)

    def resizeDialog(self):
        dialog.size().width()==200:
            dialog.resize(600,300)
        else:
            dialog.resize(200,100)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('myApp')
    dialog = myWindow()
    dialog.resize(200,100)
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PyQt4 - Smooth window resize transition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485746/pyqt4-smooth-window-resize-transition)

Comment: The link you've posted as a possible duplicate doesn't have a single line of code. The subject started there goes beyond the animation subject (overriding paint() and etc). The purpose of this question is to get a simple, clear answer on dialog size animation. There are more then enough resources here when you have to filter out 500 lines of text completely unrelated to a subject discussed. Let's keep it simple. A simple question with the screenshot, a simple code example - a simple answer as a result. What could be more beautiful than that? I hope others would appreciate simplicity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def resizeDialog(self):
    self.animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, "size")
    # self.animation.setDuration(1000) #Default 250ms
    if self.size().width()==200:
        self.animation.setEndValue(QtCore.QSize(600,300))
    else:
        self.animation.setEndValue(QtCore.QSize(200,100))
    self.animation.start()
```

The [source](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qpropertyanimation.html) linked by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485746/pyqt4-smooth-window-resize-transition) question, leads to this code. Translating from the c++ code to python is fairly straight forward in this case.